# Sorting Gridview not working with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, gridview-sorting

Hi and thanks in advance,

I am trying to sort a gridview with linq and nothing is happening. I am not getting an error, but no sorting is happening in the view either. I am also using firebug for debugging as well.

asp:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewRangeSetup" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="Gridview_Sort"
                        PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" CssClass="gridView"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewRangeSetup_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True"
                        PageSize="20" DataKeyNames="RangeId" OnRowCommand="GridViewRangeSetup_RowCommand"
                        OnRowEditing="GridViewRangeSetup_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridViewRangeSetup_CancelEditRow"
                        OnRowUpdating="GridViewRangeSetup_UpdateRow" OnRowDataBound="GridViewRangeSetup_RowDataBound">
                        <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle"></RowStyle>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerBar" ForeColor="#ffffff"></HeaderStyle>
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altRow" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#f2f2f2"
                                HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icon_edit.png" CausesValidation="false"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RangeId") %>' CommandName="Edit" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgUpdate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icon_update.png"
                                        CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RangeId") %>' CommandName="Update" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icon_cancel.png"
                                        CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RangeId") %>' CommandName="Cancel" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#F2F2F2" Width="5%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-Width="3%" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#f2f2f2"
                                HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return DeleleAlert();"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RangeId") %>' CommandName="Remove" ImageUrl="~/images/icon_delete.png" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#F2F2F2" Width="3%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country.CountryName">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" AutoPostBack="True"
                                        AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="CountryName" DataValueField="CountryId">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CountryName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State/Province" SortExpression="GeographicRegion.RegionName">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" AutoPostBack="True"
                                        AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="RegionName" DataValueField="GeographicRegionId">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegion" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegionName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Base/Facility" SortExpression="Base.BaseName">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFacility" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" AutoPostBack="True"
                                        AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="BaseName" DataValueField="BaseId">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFacility" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BaseName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Map Name" SortExpression="RangeMap.MapName">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMapName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Eval("MapName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMapName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MapName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Map">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink_Map1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"MapPath") %>'
                                        Text="">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"MapPath") %>'
                                            Width="50px" Height="50px" />
                                    </asp:HyperLink>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Low Latitude" SortExpression="RangeMap.LowLat">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLowLat" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Eval("LowLat") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLowLat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LowLat") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Low Longitude" SortExpression="RangeMap.LowLong">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLowLong" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Eval("LowLong") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLowLong" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LowLong") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="High Latitude" SortExpression="RangeMap.HighLat">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHighLat" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Eval("HighLat") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblHighLat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HighLat") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="High Longitude" SortExpression="RangeMap.HighLong">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHighLong" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Eval("HighLong") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblHighLong" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HighLong") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="RangeSetup_Status" CssClass="page-btn blue" CausesValidation="false"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RangeId") %> ' runat="server" Text="Status" OnClick="btnRangeStatus_Click">
                                    </asp:Button>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

c#

protected void Gridview_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

```
    //Label2.Text = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
    WISSModel.WISSEntities context = new WISSModel.WISSEntities();


    String column = e.SortExpression;

    IQueryable<dynamic> sortedGridview = ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection) == "ASC" ?
                                                (from r in context.Ranges.AsEnumerable()
                                                 where r.isDeleted == false
                                                 orderby typeof(WISSModel.Range).GetProperty(column).GetValue(r, null) ascending
                                                 select new
                                                 {
                                                     r.RangeId,
                                                     r.Description,
                                                     r.Country.CountryName,
                                                     r.GeographicRegion.RegionName,
                                                     r.Base.BaseName,
                                                     r.RangeMap.MapName,
                                                     r.RangeMap.MapPath,
                                                     r.RangeMap.LowLat,
                                                     r.RangeMap.LowLong,
                                                     r.RangeMap.HighLat,
                                                     r.RangeMap.HighLong
                                                 }).AsQueryable<dynamic>() :
                                                  (from r in context.Ranges.AsEnumerable()
                                                   where r.isDeleted == false
                                                   orderby typeof(WISSModel.Range).GetProperty(column).GetValue(r, null) descending
                                                   select new
                                                   {
                                                       r.RangeId,
                                                       r.Description,
                                                       r.Country.CountryName,
                                                       r.GeographicRegion.RegionName,
                                                       r.Base.BaseName,
                                                       r.RangeMap.MapName,
                                                       r.RangeMap.MapPath,
                                                       r.RangeMap.LowLat,
                                                       r.RangeMap.LowLong,
                                                       r.RangeMap.HighLat,
                                                       r.RangeMap.HighLong
                                                   }).AsQueryable<dynamic>();

    //var sortedGridview = context.Ranges.Where("it.isDeleted == false").OrderBy(column);

    GridViewRangeSetup.DataSource = sortedGridview.ToList();

    //var test = sortedGridview.ToList();

    //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    GridViewRangeSetup.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution:

Using the DataSetLinqOperators class and modifying it slightly to allow null values:

```
protected void Gridview_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {


        WISSModel.WISSEntities context = new WISSModel.WISSEntities();

        var sortedGridview = (from r in context.Ranges
                              where r.isDeleted == false
                              select new
                              {
                                  r.RangeId,
                                  r.Description,
                                  r.Country.CountryName,
                                  r.GeographicRegion.RegionName,
                                  r.Base.BaseName,
                                  r.RangeMap.MapName,
                                  r.RangeMap.MapPath,
                                  r.RangeMap.LowLat,
                                  r.RangeMap.LowLong,
                                  r.RangeMap.HighLat,
                                  r.RangeMap.HighLong
                              }).ToList();

        DataTable sortedTable = sortedGridview.CopyToDataTable();

        sortedTable.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

        GridViewRangeSetup.DataSource = sortedTable;

        GridViewRangeSetup.DataBind();

    }

    private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

        int sort = (int)ViewState["Sort"];
        switch (sort)
        {
            case 0:
                newSortDirection = "ASC";
                ViewState["Sort"] = 1;
                break;

            case 1:
                newSortDirection = "DESC";
                ViewState["Sort"] = 0;
                break;
        }

        return newSortDirection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not allowed to code order by parameters in string like in dynamic T-SQL. You should replace yout LINQ query with this one to make it work:

```
String column = e.SortExpression;
IQueryable<dynamic> sortedGridview = ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection) == "ASC" ?
                                            (from r in context.Ranges
                                             where r.isDeleted == false                                              
                                             orderby typeof(Range).GetProperty(column).GetValue(r,null) ascending
                                             select new
                                             {
                                              r.RangeId,
                                              Description = r.Description,
                                              CountryName = r.Country.CountryName,
                                              RegionName = r.GeographicRegion.RegionName,
                                              BaseName = r.Base.BaseName,
                                              r.RangeMap.MapName,
                                              r.RangeMap.MapPath,
                                              r.RangeMap.LowLat,
                                              r.RangeMap.LowLong,
                                              r.RangeMap.HighLat,
                                              r.RangeMap.HighLong
                                             }).AsQueryable<dynamic>() :
                                              (from r in context.Ranges
                                               where r.isDeleted == false                                                  
                                               orderby typeof(Range).GetProperty(column).GetValue(r, null) descending
                                               select new
                                               {
                                              r.RangeId,
                                              Description = r.Description,
                                              CountryName = r.Country.CountryName,
                                              RegionName = r.GeographicRegion.RegionName,
                                              BaseName = r.Base.BaseName,
                                              r.RangeMap.MapName,
                                              r.RangeMap.MapPath,
                                              r.RangeMap.LowLat,
                                              r.RangeMap.LowLong,
                                              r.RangeMap.HighLat,
                                              r.RangeMap.HighLong
                                               }).AsQueryable<dynamic>();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:                      **Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Comment: Try to put new variable before query: var col = typeof(Range).GetProperty(column).GetValue(r, null) and use col in query.

Comment: ok so now I am getting this error which I am not sure how to fix: **Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: @IDeveloer so my variable looks like this: **var col = typeof(Ranges).GetProperty(column).GetValue(context.Ranges,null);**, but I am sure about the getvalue method. I think thats giving me the error above.

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com//questions/4546463/help-with-linq-and-generics-using-getvalue-inside-a-query

Comment: ummm would it be easier to use LINQ to do the sorting?

Comment: You are using LINQ already. About 'object reference..'-exception, what exactly is null? Use debugger to determine it. What is the value of col? The link I gave should help you to remove that exception: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I forgot to put Model in the col variable. I edited what I had currently above. I'm now getting this error:    **Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object does not match target type.**

Comment: You got that exception on line where col variable is initialized? I assumed that you have Range type, it's true? Next you should check in debugger value of column variable. Range type must have a property with the name of column variable value. Are all these conditions satisfied? What's the value of col after all?

Comment: I made some research and made it work for me. You need to do: 1. In LINQ query add .AsEnumerable() to `context.Ranges` so it should be `context.Ranges.AsEnumerable()`; 2. Remove col variable and write as before `orderby typeof(Range).GetProperty(column).GetValue(r,null) ascending/descending`. I just tried it, it works perfectly.

Comment: I edited I what have thus far above. Current error is:  **Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Comment: ummmm my gridview does have some null or empty fields. I wonder if that is the problem.

Comment: On which line is that exception thrown?

Comment: Check the value of column variable, I guess it will be smth like 'colname ASC/DESC'. You need to get only colname: column.Split(' ')[0] for example.

Comment: error: I ran the debugger and its blowing up   **new Select { {r.RangeId,
                                              Description = r.Description,
                                              CountryName = r.Country.CountryName,
                                              RegionName = r.GeographicRegion.RegionName,
                                              BaseName = r.Base.BaseName, etc}**, it giving a **System.NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}**

Comment: You meant `select new { ... }` not `new select { ... }`? Next, `r.Country.CountryName` is available? Try to write a separate query like `context.Ranges.First().Country.CoutryName` and see, if it is null or not. I suppose that `Country` is a navigation property, so you may need to include table of countries in your sorting query.

Comment: Yes meant I select new. So I deleted the rows that have null values and when I click the description column, it sorts asc., but doesn't desc. Other columns are still giving the same error. In the backend, Country is another db table and the field is countryname which you see is accessed in the query as 'r.Coyuntry.CountryName'.

Comment: so right now I have 3 problems: **1) query doesn't handle fields with null values . 2) Won't sort in DESC direction. 3) Sorting columns that have references( foregin keys) to other tables such as Country**

Comment: Check `ConvertSortDirectionToSql` method if it returns DESC when it's descending sort order. If it's ok, than store last direction somewhere (Session, for example) and switch it when needed. Join tables required for foreign keys values. That should solve #2 and #3, about #1 I'm not sure, but I think you need to handle `null` values in `RowDataBound` method to replace them with values (empty string, 0 etc.)

Comment: oh ok, for #1 I will change the Textboxes that have null values to empty strings in the RowDataBound method and let you know.

Comment: I tried changing the null textboxes to empty string with no success.I was able to figure something out for #2 by using viewstates.